# CEP da minha cidade, onde posso encontrar fonte aberta, atualizada e confiável?

Tags: banco-de-dados, cep, código-aberto, código-postal, dados-abertos

O [Código de Endereçamento Postal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_de_Endere%C3%A7amento_Postal), CEP (ou *ZIP code*) dos endereços de uma cidade garantem maior confiabilidade aos *dados de endereço* e à [resolução de geolocalização por endereço](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding)... Lembrando que *endereço* não se presta somente ao envio de carta pelo correio, é um complemento essencial ao cadastro de uma [pessoa física](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pessoa_(direito)) (localização mesmo que aproximada de onde reside) ou [jurídica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pessoa_jur%C3%ADdica) (endereço da sede da empresa), presente em bases de dados de CRMs, ERPs, etc. e  padrões tais como [vCard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard), [Schema](http://schema.org/Organization), e centenas de outros.

A pergunta é **"Onde estão os dados da minha cidade?"**, e pode ter uma resposta específica para cada país da língua portuguesa, assim como, eventualmente, para cada cidade (!), pois as cidades tem certa autonomia sobre o tema. Como tomei como exemplo a cidade de Campinas, fica a sugestão de restringirmos discussões a Campinas.

No caso do Brasil, os dados não estão nem sob a responsabilidade do IBGE nem sob a responsabilidade da Prefeitura, apesar da prefeitura ser a responsável pelas "leis de batismo" de cada nome de rua da cidade ([exemplo de rua de Campinas](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn:lex:br;sao.paulo;campinas:municipal:lei:1953-06-23;943)).

---

#### NOTAS

- O *Geonames* tem se empenhado em construir um esboço dessa base de dados, mas não resolve.
- O *OpenStreetMap* parece ter uma parte dos dados (!). De fato, o ideal para o CEP é te-lo espacializado (dada uma coordenada geográfica da cidade, retornar o CEP da coordenada).
- O Diretório Nacional de Endereços (DNE) é a base de dados mantida pela Empresa Brasileira de Correios e Telegrafos (ECT), mais conhecida como "Correios" do Brasil, para validar endereços postais e determinar  CEPs. Ela não pode estar numa base apoiada pelo [CKAN](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CKAN) ou qualquer outra iniciativa de *Dados Abertos*.

Comment: Acho que nessa pergunta já se concluiu que não existe alternativa e por isto talvez seja uma duplicata: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/400/101

Comment: @bigown, Sim, muito parecida, mas considero a abordagem aqui diferente: é estritamente sobre *dados abertos*, ou  iniciativas para captura legalizada desses dados... Enfim, um *"workaround"* mais sólido.

Comment: Eu entendi isto, é que lá se concluiu que não existe.

Comment: A pergunta é sobre buscar endereços a partir de CEPs, vice-versa ou, por geo-localização, tudo isso? - Conheço uma integração gratuita direto à base dos correios que permite localizar endereço por CEP, posso postar, se for esse o foco.

Comment: @GêBender Verifique primeiro se já não tem isso na [outra pergunta sobre CEPs](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/400/101).

Comment: Valeu @utluiz, realmente já tem uma resposta com um script bem parecido, é um crawler do site mobile dos correios. Tenho usado há um bom tempo (uns anos) e me atendendo bem, praticamente sem quedas ou qualquer problema do tipo. Mas, sempre há o risco dos correios fecharem a porta, colocarem captcha, etc. Quem quiser o código, entre em contato.

Comment: O postmon não tem o que você precisa?

Comment: Pode tentar usar um crawler e fazer sua própria base de dados.

Comment: O que acho mais confiável atualmente é o Google Maps. Utilizo a API do GoogleMaps para fazer buscas por CEP e o resultado é bastante satisfatório. O único problema com a API do Google Maps é que tem um limite de uso a cada 24horas por cada IP, acho que 100.000 requisições. Mas se seu site não for muito grande, a API do Maps dá conta do recado. Abs

Comment: Uma variação da pergunta, porém mais específica sobre **mapas** e sobre **CEP5** (não CEP8) foi postada em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73640/4186

Comment: viacep.com.br/ws/76821348/json/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Resumo sobre a solicitação pelo e-SIC:

Tendo conhecimento sobre a lei de acesso a informação, através do e-SIC, enviei um pedido aos CORREIOS desta base pelo órgão superior ECT - Empresa Brasileira de Correios e Telégrafos.

Como resposta, enviaram-me o link http://www.shopping.correios.com.br/ para que eu adquirisse a base, fortalecendo que os correios são regidos por leis que norteiam suas atividades. Enviei como recurso de primeira instância reforçando o pedido e mais uma vez enviaram-me o link do shopping dos correios. Ainda insistindo, enviei como recurso de segunda instância diretamente ao presidente dos CORREIOS o senhor Wagner Pinheiro, informando que a [Lei 6.538/78](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn:lex:br:federal:lei:1978-06-22;6538)  que permite a empresa comercializar sua base de dados (mencionada por eles) é mais antiga que a Lei de Acesso a informação, a qual tem precedência sobre a lei do serviço postal. Obtive como resposta "A base de dados do CEP, objeto de sua solicitação é um produto comercializado pelos Correios." e mandaram-me o link dos correios para consultas gratuitas (porém o que eu quero é a base completa) e assim mais uma vez enviaram-me o link do shopping dos correios.

Ao final da resposta do recurso da segunda instância: "Eventuais recursos devem ser dirigidos a Controladoria Geral da União, de acordo com o Art. 23 do [Decreto 7.724/2012](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn:lex:br:federal:decreto:2012-05-16;7724) que regulamenta a Lei de Acesso a Informação - Lei 12.527/2011, no prazo de 10 dias, a contar do recebimento desta resposta."

Como já se passaram dois dias, agora tenho 8 dias para resolver este problema e gostaria de saber como proceder.

---

Abaixo a *thread* completa:

### Primeira solicitação

> Olá, 
>   Gostaria de uma base com todos os CEPs do Brasil. Enfim, com todas as informações de localidade correspondentes aos CEPs.
>   Agradeço.

**Resposta:**

A ECT, por meio do Busca CEP, disponibiliza no site http://www.buscacep.correios.com.br/ , a todo cidadão, a consulta gratuita do Código de Endereçamento Postal – CEP de forma individualizada.

Como empresa pública, os Correios são regidos por leis que norteiam suas atividades.
Em conformidade com a [Lei 6.538/78](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn:lex:br:federal:lei:1978-06-22;6538)  que regula os direitos e obrigações concernentes ao Serviço Postal, notadamente pela por força do artigo 8º, inc. II, a ECT  pode comercializar a sua base de dados do CEP, conforme transcrito abaixo:
“8º São atividades correlatas ao serviço postal: ll-Venda de publicações divulgando regulamentos, normas, tarifas, listas de código de endereçamento e outros assuntos referentes ao serviço postal”.

A base de dados do CEP é fornecida por meio do produto e-DNE nas modalidades Básico e Master, e pode ser adquirido na loja virtual 
http://www.shopping.correios.com.br/.

Os Correios agradece a sua compreensão.

ANTONIO DE PAULA BRAQUEHAIS

Chefe do DEPRO

DEPARTAMENTO DE PRODUTOS DE COMUNICAÇÃO-DEPRO

Eventuais recursos devem ser dirigidos ao Vice-Presidente de Negócios, de acordo com o Art. 21 do [Decreto 7.724/2012](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn:lex:br:federal:decreto:2012-05-16;7724) que regulamenta a Lei de Acesso a Informação - [Lei 12.527/2011](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn:lex:br:federal:lei:2011-11-18;12527), no prazo de 10 dias, a contar do recebimento desta resposta.

Serviço de Informação ao Cidadão
Empresa Brasileira de Correios e Telégrafos

### Recurso de primeira instância

> Eu gostaria de uma base onde eu encontrasse o codigo do estado, o estado, o codigo da cidade, a cidade, o codigo do bairro, o bairro, a rua e seu CEP. Enfim, tudo sobre localização com base nos logradouros.
>   Abraços!

**Resposta:**

Prezado Senhor Judson,

A base de dados do CEP é fornecida  por meio do produto DNE nas modalidades  Básico e Master, e pode ser adquirido na loja virtual http://www.shopping.correios.com.br/.

A ECT por meio do Busca CEP, disponibiliza no site
http://www.buscacep.correios.com.br/, a todo cidadão, a consulta gratuita do Código de Endereçamento Postal - CEP de forma individualizada .
Os Correios agradecem a sua compreensão.

Morgana Cristina Santos
Vice-Presidente de Negócios

Eventuais recursos devem ser dirigidos ao Presidente dos Correios, de acordo com o Art. 21 do Decreto 7.724/2012 que regulamenta a Lei de Acesso a Informação - Lei 12.527/2011, no prazo de 10 dias, a contar do recebimento desta resposta.

Serviço de Informação ao Cidadão

Empresa Brasileira de Correios e Telégrafos

### Recurso de Segunda Instância:

> Ao Senhor Wagner Pinheiro
>
> Presidente da CORREIOS S/A
>
> Venho através deste, impetrar recurso administrativo em segunda instância, referente ao pedido de informação XXX referente a solicitação de cópia digital da Base de dados de CEP - Modalidade Master.
>
> Em resposta nas instâncias anteriores, o CORREIOS nos informou que a [Lei 6.538/78](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn:lex:br:federal:lei:1978-06-22;6538) permite a empresa comercializar sua base de dados, com fulcro no teor do artigo 8º desta lei:
>
> “8º São atividades correlatas ao serviço postal: ll-Venda de publicações divulgando regulamentos, normas, tarifas, listas de código de endereçamento e outros assuntos referentes ao serviço postal”.
>
> Todavia, entendemos que a Lei de Acesso a Informação, (12.527/2011), por ser uma lei mais recente que a lei que regulamenta o serviço postal (6538/78), tem precedência sobre a mesma. Cumpre destacar que as empresas públicas, como os CORREIOS, também são subordinadas à Lei de Acesso a Informação, conforme seu Art 1º, Inciso II
>
> Art. 1º  Esta Lei dispõe sobre os procedimentos a serem observados pela União, Estados, Distrito Federal e Municípios, com o fim de garantir o acesso a informações previsto no inciso XXXIII do art. 5o, no inciso II do § 3º do art. 37 e no § 2º do art. 216 da [Constituição Federal](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn:lex:br:federal:constituicao:1988-10-05;1988).
>
> Parágrafo único.  Subordinam-se ao regime desta Lei:
>
> I - os órgãos públicos integrantes da administração direta dos Poderes Executivo, Legislativo, incluindo as Cortes de Contas, e Judiciário e do Ministério Público;
>
> II - as autarquias, as fundações públicas, as empresas públicas, as sociedades de economia mista e demais entidades controladas direta ou indiretamente pela União, Estados, Distrito Federal e Municípios
>   Cumpre registrar que a Lei de Acesso a Informação, em especial o seu Artº 10 não apresenta nenhuma disposição que restrinja a disponibilização de informações comercializáveis. Entendemos ainda que ao solicitar uma cópia digital da base de CEPs, não estamos infringindo o teor da [Lei 6.538/78](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn:lex:br:federal:lei:1978-06-22;6538), pois não há intenção em impedir a comercialização da base de CEPs para quem quiser comprá-la. Apenas estamos solicitando uma cópia gratuitamente com base na previsão legal da Lei de Acesso a Informação.
>   Assim sendo, solicito vossa atenção ao recurso administrativo em questão, buscando atingir o objetivo de obtenção de uma cópia digital da base de CEPs, conforme exposição de motivos acima.

**Resposta:**

Prezado Senhor,
“A base de dados do CEP, objeto de sua solicitação é um produto comercializado pelos Correios. A informação de forma  individualizada encontra-se disponível, por meio do Busca CEP, no site WWW.correios.com.br, que possibilita a qualquer cidadão consultar gratuitamente o Código de Endereçamento Postal – CEP, nas seguintes formas:

1. CEP ou Endereço;
2. CEP por localidade/Logradouro;
3. Endereço por CEP;
4. CEP de Logradouro por Bairro;
5. Faixas de CEP;
6. CEPs de unidades operacionais;
7. CEPs especiais;
8. Caixa postal comunitária;
9. CEP por caixa postal;
10. CEP promocional.

As informações compiladas são fornecidas por meio do produto e-DNE nas modalidades Básico e Master, que é adquirido na loja virtual http://www.shopping.correios.com.br/. O Diretório Nacional de Endereços – DNE é considerado obra intelectual nova e original, nos termos da Lei Nº 9.610/1998 – Lei de Direitos Autorais. A referida invenção se constitui em base de dados, cujos direitos patrimoniais de autor estão sob a titularidade exclusiva da Empresa Brasileira de Correios e Telégrafos – ECT, inclusive por força dos artigos 2º,§1º,”b”; 8º, inc. II e 15º, §1º da [Lei 6.538/78](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn:lex:br:federal:lei:1978-06-22;6538), podendo ser licenciado por meio de contratação direta, com respaldo no caput do art. 25 da Lei nº 8.666/93. Em 04/10/2002, a ECT depositou e é legítima titular perante o Instituto Nacional de Propriedade Industrial (INPI) do pedido de Patente de Invenção, sob o Nº PI 0.204.305-0, titulado “DIRETÓRIO NACIONAL DE ENDEREÇOS (DNE)”. Em 07/10/2003, a ECT depositou e é legítima titular da extensão da patente de invenção, indicada no subitem 1.1.3, perante o German Patent Applicatations, sob nº 10.346.551.0.

Diante do exposto, decido pelo conhecimento do presente recurso, para, no mérito, negar provimento, com fulcro no art. 13, III do Decreto 7.724/2012.

Os Correios agradecem a sua compreensão.

Wagner Pinheiro de Oliveira

PRESIDENTE

Empresa Brasileira de Correios e Telégrafos

Eventuais recursos devem ser dirigidos a Controladoria Geral da União, de acordo com o Art. 23 do Decreto 7.724/2012 que regulamenta a Lei de Acesso a Informação - Lei 12.527/2011, no prazo de 10 dias, a contar do recebimento desta resposta.

Serviço de Informação ao Cidadão

Empresa Brasileira de Correios e Telégrafos

Comment: Obrigado por compartilhar! Temos pouco tempo... Quem for *expert* em redação jurídica ou estiver disposto a ajudar o Judson na resposta, pode entrar em contato aqui ou [na lista OKBr](http://open-knowledge-foundation-brasil-rede-pelo-conhecimento-livre.50579.x6.nabble.com/okfn-br-Problemas-para-conseguir-a-base-dos-CEPs-atraves-dos-CORREIOS-tt4297.html)

Comment: vou criar mais uma "falsa resposta" a esta pergunta para abrigar na forma de Wiki o texto colaborativo de recurso à CGU... Que acha?

Comment: Sim, pode ser..

Comment: O prazo acaba amanhã ou segunda?

Comment: Qual foi o resultado da petição?

Answer (score 17):

Infelizmente, todas as informações disponíveis apontam para a resposta de que **não há uma base de CEPs que seja aberta, atualizada e confiável**.

Segundo a [Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_de_Endere%C3%A7amento_Postal) os Correios criaram e mantém a base de CEPs, ou seja, ela pertence à empresa, não é uma informação pública por padrão.

## Base atualizada e confiável

Como pode ser consultado por qualquer pessoa no site dos Correios, a base eletrônica oficial e suas atualizações podem ser adquiridas como um [produto chamado DNE](http://www.correios.com.br/para-voce/correios-de-a-a-z/dne). A descrição do site diz:

> É a base oficial e exclusiva dos Correios, sendo assim, a informação é confiável e atualizada.

O [custo](http://www.correios.com.br/para-voce/consultas-e-solicitacoes/precos-e-prazos/servicos-nacionais_pasta/e-dne) inicial (em 04/2015) vai de R$ 1.100,00 a R$ 2.100,00, fora as renovações para receber as atualizações trimestrais do cadastro.

Segundo os [detalhes do produto](http://shopping.correios.com.br/wbm/store/script/wbm2400901p01.aspx?cd_company=ErZW8Dm9i54=&cd_product=A9xD9pRAEQA=&cd_department=SsNp3FlaUpM=), a base é disponibilizada em dois formatos:

1. Arquivo texto (.txt)
2. Base de dados do Microsoft Access (.mdb)

## Outros serviços

Outras empresas podem adquirir a base de CEPs e disponibilizar serviços para consulta, pagos ou gratuitos. Entretanto, elas são diretamente dependentes das atualizações dos correios. Veja [este artigo](http://www.autocep.com.br/tabela-de-ceps.html), por exemplo.

Particularmente, acho difícil encontrar uma base atualizada gratuita, pois o proprietário teria de arcar com os custos do produto e das atualizações dos Correios e ainda manter um Web Service de alta disponibilidade.

## Bases abertas

Alguns sites e até blogs disponibilizam bases de dados para download. Porém, essas bases não podem ser consideradas confiáveis ou atualizadas, já que não há uma garantia de que os dados estejam realmente corretos e que as atualizações da base representam as últimas atualizações dos correios.

Não conheço as implicações legais, mas creio que algumas dessas soluções são ilegais, se as mesmas estão apenas disponibilizando o banco de dados vendido pelos correios em outro formato.

## Conclusão

Existem hoje fontes de CEPs confiáveis e atualizadas porém pagas (Correios) e fontes abertas porém não confiáveis e talvez não atualizadas (outros sites).

Para empresas, por exemplo as que trabalham com lojas virtuais, o investimento na base dos Correios seria a melhor saída.

Para projetos pessoais, utilizar uma base menos confiável seria bastante aceitável, principalmente se houver possibilidade de atualização manual quando necessário.

Comment: "ou seja, ela pertence à empresa" - Vale notar que quem criou [foi uma autarquia federal, depois entidade pública federal](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empresa_Brasileira_de_Correios_e_Telégrafos), e não uma empresa particular. E a base era aberta ao público, seu fechamento foi mais uma manobra absurda que só acontece em lugares como o Brasil.

Comment: @Bacco Sim, mas seja uma empresa pública ou privada, não faz diferença. Às vezes nós temos a noção de que por uma empresa ser pública então todas as informações dela deveriam ser abertas, serviços e produtos deveriam ser gratuitos, etc., mas na realidade não é nada disso.

Comment: Não todas, mas as de interesse público, com certeza. Essa "semi-privatização" dos Correios foi mais uma das mazelas políticas do nosso País, com interesses no meu ver, duvidosos.

Comment: @Bacco Sim, algumas por medida de lei, quando o cidadão tem o "direito" a tal e tal serviço, então o Governo subsidia, pagando por ele de alguma forma, como é o caso do SUS, por exemplo.

Comment: Não dá pra comparar as duas coisas. O SUS necessita de volumes de dinheiro para existir, tal base de dados já existe pela natureza do serviço (público) prestado pelos Correios, não há custo que justifique o que é cobrado pela base. E toda a manutenção da entidade já é feita pela cobrança dos serviços e meios que você mencionou. Não vou me estender mais, pela questão do escopo da resposta, mas acho importante que as pessoas se conscientizem que não é tão simples assim.

Comment: @Bacco Tem razão, não é a mesma coisa. Porém, isso não muda o fato de que esse valor integra o lucro da empresa. Se a informação fosse disponibilizada de graça, ou o lucro líquido diminuiria ou os Correios aumentariam o preço de outro serviço. Acho que no fim o nosso erro é achar que empresas públicas como os Correios não visam o lucro como qualquer outra empresa.

Comment: Prezados @Bacco e UTLuiz, acrescentei uma "resposta" para podermos discutir o que talvez seja o ponto-chave da pergunta.

Comment: Boa abordagem @utluiz, e é isso mesmo, hoje não temos muito além do que você citou, ou é por aqui, ou é por aqui mesmo.

Comment: @Fernando, repare o item 3.1 das "[alternativas legais](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56664/4186)"...

Comment: @utluiz, pelas regras você fica com a recompensa, merecida (!): se achar que não, eu clico aqui, me avisa. Pelo meu critério não teve resposta: ninguém mostrou  "onde posso encontrar fonte aberta, atualizada e confiável"... o que era de se esperar (mas não quero que fique parecendo pegadinha proposital)... Talvez eu marque no futuro como "*accepted*" a minha indicação de "Alternativas legais", por ser um "algoritmo para a resposta" :-)

Comment: Eu encontrei um banco completo com os CEPs do Brasil que podem ser acessados de forma gratuita através deste link: https://www.back4app.com/database/back4app/api-cep-correios

Answer (score 14):

(não é resposta mas VOTE negativo ou positivo para expressar seu parecer!)

(é uma WIKI: edite a vontade para indicar melhor a posição)

---

### Alternativas legais possíveis

O que se diz por aí, e talvez o momento seja oportuno para testar com mais empenho por parte da sociedade organizada, é que o CEP é um bem público, um **[dado aberto](http://dados.gov.br/dados-abertos/)**, não-apropriável por uma empresa... Enumerando para poder citar os argumentos nos comentários e discussões:

1. Os nomes das coisas públicas de uma cidade (lugar público, eventos, etc.) são igualmente públicos. Quem tem o poder de dar nomes aos logradouros das cidades no Brasil, é o governo municipal, tradicionalmente as Câmaras Municipais. [**Exemplo**](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn:lex:br;sao.paulo;campinas:municipal:lei:1948-10-06;86). Os identificadores numéricos públicos são conceitualmente "nomes"... 
   Para efeitos legais, **o CEP é um nome público do município**. 
   NOTA TÉCNICA: nomes podem ter função de ID, e IDs podem ter função de nomes, o conceito que une as duas coisas é o nome uniforme, [*URN*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_name). O CEP é também, para todos os efeitos, um tipo de *URN*.
2. Se uma Lei estabelece regras a serem seguidas pelas empresas e cidadãos, essa Lei não pode ser paga... 
    (a [Constituição](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn:lex:br:federal:constituicao:1988-10-05;1988) obriga a publicação do texto de qualquer lei, **art. 37**, e garante a franquia ao acesso desse mesmo texto, **art. 216, § 2º**)

   2.1. **Existem leis que nos obrigam a preencher formulários com endereço e CEP**, logo, por consequência lógica da "obrigação por Lei de preencher o CEP", não pode haver cobrança do "banco de dados de CEPs".

   2.2. Imaginemos o texto de uma "Lei do CEP": uma listagem de cada trecho de logradouro da cidade sendo batizado por um [ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_identifier), dito *CEP*. 
   A "Lei do CEP" é hoje um texto pago e privado... Todavia, segundo a Constituição brasileira (artigos listados acima), um texto de Lei, incluindo partes como tabelas e listas, deve ser um [dado aberto](http://dados.gov.br/dados-abertos/). 
   PS: um vereador ou mesmo a [iniciativa popular](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iniciativa_popular#Brasil) podem criar a "Lei do CEP" do seu  município, explicitando as listas de CEP em texto oficial, tal como é feito com nomes de rua.
3. O suposto "direito de **monopólio**" pela prestação do "serviço de batismo", eventualmente concedido no passado (não houve *consulta pública* nem confirmação de constituicionalidade), à "empresa batizadora de CEPs", **não pode ser eterno**, precisa encerrar após o período de exploração do retorno do investimento...

   3.1. Para efeitos práticos e éticos, essa data já expirou, o serviço já "se pagou".

   3.2. Hoje (2015) não se justifica mais cobrar por tal serviço, o [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org), [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/) e ferramentas gratuítas como o [PostGIS](http://postgis.org/), demonstram o quanto os *"algoritmos de batismo espacialmente consistente"*  são simples: cabe à comunidade técnica (nós aqui!) demonstrar que esse algoritmo é gratuito e o governo pode usar sem precisar pagar para uma empresa privada "desenvolver".
4. O CEP pode ser caracterizado como **bem de utilidade pública**, e o município pode formalmente expressar a  "declaração de utilidade pública em seus domínios" (ver item 1).

---

... Mais argumentos jurídicos? Edite, aqui é uma WIKI! ...

Comment: O 2.1 acho um bom argumento. Não vou entrar muito no mérito jurídico (apesar da minha formação), pois pra mim o problema é antes de mais nada de ordem moral e típico de um país que não é sério. Este tipo de cobrança ignora completamente o interesse público, e privilegia grandes empresas.

Comment: Mais argumentos consolidados: http://codigourbano.org/por-que-o-cep-deve-ser-tratado-como-informacao-publica/

Answer (score 7):

Até agora, a mais completa que achei foi em um fórum onde o usuário postou que procurou por meio dos correios (não falou como) e que conseguiu uma atualizada até fev. 2015, se não me engano.

Disponibilizei para quem quiser baixar [aqui](http://www.fileshare.ro/e31477206).

Uma alternativa seria solicitar também pelo [e-SIC](http://www.acessoainformacao.gov.br/sistema/site/acesso_info.html).

Answer (score 5):

Já perdi algumas noites em claro tentando encontrar uma alternativa que me desse confiabilidade sobre a base dos CEPs, sem que fosse possível pagar para os correios. A que encontrei foi a utilização das APIs citadas anteriormente, mas não garantem confiabilidade. Acabei tirando a prioridade sobre isso. E agora estou precisando novamente.

A Lei de Acesso à Informação "regulamenta o direito constitucional de acesso às informações públicas" [1]

De acordo com o próprio site dos correios, nele são disponibilizadas informações públicas e que são de interesse coletivo. [2]

Portanto, apesar de não ter formação em direito, acredito que através da LAI a base de CEPs deve ser disponibilizada integralmente, já que trata-se de informação de interesse coletivo, inclusive pode ser consultada no site manualmente, então não vai gerar nenhum custo para os correios caso disponibilize como um dado aberto.

Farei uma solicitação através do SIC, divulgarei aqui quando receber uma resposta.

[1] http://www.acessoainformacao.gov.br/assuntos/conheca-seu-direito/a-lei-de-acesso-a-informacao

[2] http://www.correios.com.br/sobre-correios/acesso-a-informacao

Comment: Williams, algum retorno?

Comment: Olá, Diego.

Postei uma nova resposta com toda a solicitação e as respostas.

Answer (score 4):

A cobrança neste preço é abusiva, absurda.

Num post do blog dos correios já rolou uma discussão, e teve até um cara dizendo que ia procurar os representantes políticos "para que eles expliquem como um órgão público pode cobrar por acesso completo a dados públicos".

A resposta padrão dos Correios (muito irritante) é a seguinte:

> Como mencionado no post, a consulta à base de CEP de todo o Brasil para a postagem de correspondências continua sendo oferecida de forma gratuita pelos Correios, por meio de guias nas agências ou pelo Busca CEP, no site dos Correios (www.correios.com.br).

[No mesmo post](http://blog.correios.com.br/correios/?p=1581) foram citadas algumas fontes, que não são oficiais, e [esta](http://www.qualocep.com/base-de-cep/) (que é paga, mas num preço razoável) me pareceu a mais confiável.

Durante minha pesquisa achei [este post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-brasil/wvERTS9Bz3M) (de 2012!) sobre o assunto, num grupo do google, onde um cara fez uma denúncia no site [Acesso à Informação](http://www.acessoainformacao.gov.br/). Veja o que ele diz:

> Coloquei lá no http://www.acessoainformacao.gov.br/ minha solicitação 
>   nestes termos:
>
> Muitos sistemas necessitam acesso à base de dados do CEP, porém a ECT 
>   coloca barreiras técnicas e financeiras ao acesso a estes dados. A 
>   falta de acesso livre a esta base de dados causa a disseminação de 
>   cópias desatualizadas, o que prejudica não apenas os usuários mas a 
>   própria ECT, uma vez que ela é obrigada a entregar correspondência 
>   mesmo com o CEP informado incorretamente. Portanto é do interesse do 
>   público e da própria ECT que estes dados sejam oferecidos de forma 
>   livre através de uma API (interface de programação) aberta e de fácil 
>   utilização. 
>   """
>
> O que acontece, uma vez um analista de sistemas da ECT me contou, é 
>   que **existe uma "unidade de negócios" na ECT que se encarrega de 
>   comercializar a base do CEP. Na realidade, segundo ele, essa 
>   comercialização paga os salários de alguns gestores e vendedores, mas 
>   causa prejuízo à ECT por que ela perde mais dinheiro com o tratamento 
>   de correspondência com CEP faltando ou incorreto do que lucra 
>   "vendendo" a base do CEP**. Ironicamente, os maiores usuários desta 
>   base, como as teles, bancos etc. na realidade *não pagam por ela* 
>   porque o custo de licença da base do CEP acaba sendo apenas um item 
>   insignificante na negociação global de contratos com estes grandes 
>   clientes!

Por fim, em complemento ao excelente post sobre este a questão jurídica (acima) entendo cabível um mandando de segurança (se fossem informações particulares seria um habeas data) na Justiça Federal, baseado nos argumentos que o colega citou, mas, principalmente, tendo em vista o altíssimo valor cobrado ([nos eua tbm é cobrado, mas coisa de 39$ a 249$](http://zipcodedownload.com/)).

Até faria sentido cobrar por um produto com muitas vantagens (diferente do CBO por exemplo, que vem em pdf e dificulta a vida, como falei [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57850/extrair-dados-de-arquivo-txt-para-usar-em-autocomplete-do-cbo-c%C3%B3digo-brasileiro)), mas este preço é ridículo, impraticável. Além disso, poderiam disponibilizar a base num arquivo .txt por exemplo, sem o software desenvolvido, para quem quisesse utilizar a base de forma gratuita.

Acredito que não exista qualquer outro tipo de produto (de informação) fornecido por qualquer outro órgão concessionário do governo com um preço tão absurdo destes.

Bom, espero não ter falado demais e ter colaborado com o tópico (em que pese o alto grau opinativo da resposta). :-)

Comment: Eu vejo no futuro esses dados sendo acessados por uma API gratuitamente, o que falta é alguém inteligente lá dentro resolver essa questão. É impossível o Brasil ir pra frente com esses entraves que prejudicam pequenas empresas, isso é típico de pessoas retrogradas que estão no poder desses setores e já deveriam ter sido migradas para áreas que não precise usar o cérebro.

Answer (score 3):

Não sei com que frequencia esta base é atualizada, mas esse serviço está no ar há varios anos e nunca caiu.

Eles também disponibilizam a base para download.

[http://republicavirtual.com.br/cep](http://republicavirtual.com.br/cep/)

Comment: Boa dica (!)... Mas duplicada, [veja a discussão anterior](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/414/4186). O que se concluiu por lá foi que o RepublicaVirtual e outros tantos, oferecem uma base bem desatualizada, e sem uma comunidade mantenedora, como o [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/), [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/), etc... Mesmo sem mapas, existem metodologias de colaboração e atualização como [esse exemplo da OpenKnowledge](https://github.com/datasets/country-codes/). Como existem dúvidas juridicas/legais, nenhuma entidade dessas assume um repositório sério e atualizado de CEP.

Comment: Fato. Infelizmente não temos como consultar a nossa própria base oficial dos Correios. Um absurdo em minha opinião, pois isso deveria ser de direito de qualquer um.

Answer (score 2):

(isto não é resposta, é uma Wiki p. depois juntar de volta na [resposta do Judson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63936/4186))

[PAD encerrado](https://pad.okfn.org/p/CEP-recurso-CGU2015-05) ou a lista de emails que vamos conferindo.
RASCUNHO [**v0.6** de 2015-05-21](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/64643/revisions), revisão encerrada.

### Texto colaborativo para recurso à CGU

À Controladoria Geral da União,

A não-divulgação da *Lista de CEPs* **é inconstitucional**, pois a Constituição (art. 37) requer a publicidade  da Lista de CEPs completa em formato digital aberto e acessível ao cidadão. **Não requer** a distribuição gratuíta de um "produto" (o DNE, que pode ser entendido como uma "embalagem" da Lista de CEPs).

1. *Interpretações auxiliares*:

   1.1. **Lista de CEPs do município**. É uma lista completa, de todos os códigos de CEP com incidência sobre o município, e a cada CEP a indicação detalhada dos logradouros  (e seus respectivos bairros, subdistritos e distritos)  ou trechos de logradouro (faces de quadra) que compõe cada CEP. Essa lista (também designada "informações compiladas") deve ser oferecida em formato digital (ex. arquivos CSV), tal qual fixado em http://dados.gov.br/dados-abertos/

   1.2. **O CEP é um bem público, seu "dono" é o município**. Os *nomes* das coisas públicas de uma cidade (lugar público, eventos, etc.) são igualmente públicos. Quem tem o poder de dar nomes aos logradouros das cidades no Brasil, é o governo municipal, tradicionalmente as Câmaras Municipais.  O código de CEP é um "nome oficial", um elemento agregador de nomes de logradouros do município; por extensão, o "dono" do CEP é o poder municipal.

   1.3. *A Lista de CEPs é um bem de **utilidade pública**, que faz parte da infra-estrutura informacional da cidade*. O seu caráter "de utilidade pública" é reconhecido e incontestável, de modo que, tal como um terreno ou um equipamento social, a alegação de *propriedade privada* pode ser contestada legitimamente e em favor dos direitos e da vontade dos munícipes.  Segundo os Artsº 3, Inciso II, 5º e 6º, Inciso I da Lei Federal 12.527/2011, empresas públicas como a Empresa Brasileira de Correios e Telégrafos (ECT) precisa divulgar informações de interesse público, garantindo o direito de acesso a informação de forma transparente e clara, propiciando amplo acesso às mesmas.  Cumpre ressaltar ainda que, o Art. 8º da Lei de Acesso a Informação dispõe objetivamente sobre os deveres de órgãos e entidades públicas quando a disponibilização de informações de interesse coletivo ou geral por eles produzidos ou custodiadas, que é o caso da Lista de CEPs.

   1.4. Considerando o Art. 4º do Decreto Federal 7.724/2013, que regulamenta a Lei de Acesso à Informação, a busca e o fornecimento de informações são gratuitos, ressalvada a cobrança do valor referente ao custo dos serviços. Neste interim, pode-se demonstrar que não existe custo justificável nesse tipo de operação, que já não tenha sido amplamente ressarcido pelos anos de exploração comercial da "embalagem" da  Lista de CEPs que já foram concedidos à pela empresa.  Complementarmente, a suposta tecnologia para acrescentar novos CEPs à *Lista de CEPs* do município, é simples e de amplo domínio do público nos dias de hoje, tornando obsoletas quaisquer justificativas em torno do seu custo de manutenção. Se a CGU requisitar podemos oferecer um amplo estudo demonstrativo, inclusive da ineficácia do atual operador e autoridade do sistema de atribuição de CEPs.

   1.4.1. Pode-se demonstrar que não existe custo justificável nesse tipo de operação, que já não tenha sido amplamente ressarcido pelos anos de exploração comercial que já foram concedidos à empresa. O interesse difuso hoje é organizado e produz tecnologias sofisticadas a exemplo da [www.geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org) ou [www.openstreetmap.org](http://www.openstreetmap.org), tendo além disso apoio de prefeituras, de empresas de saneamento e energia, ainda hoje prejudicadas pela demora da atribuição do CEP (acarretando perdas em contas de IPTU, água e luz).

   1.5. **As Leis do Brasil são um bem público, aberto e acessível, e todo conteúdo citado por uma Lei deve ser igualmente aberto e acessível**. Trata-se do que vulgarmente se denomina "contaminação do acesso à Lei": figuras, mapas, tabelas, listas, qualquer objeto citado pelo texto de uma Lei deve ser igualmente acessível.  *Normas técnicas* que direta (por citação) ou indiretamente regulamentam as exigências da Lei, são também entendidas como "objetos citados".

   1.5.1. Um exemplo típico de solução para esse passívo, é o *termo de ajuste do conduta* da ABNT http://www.pessoacomdeficiencia.gov.br/app/normas-da-abnt/termo-de-ajustamento-de-conduta

   1.6. A alegada "informação de forma individualizada", ou seja, programas de computador disponibilizados em rede que efetuam a chamada "resolução de um CEP indivídual":

   1.6.1. não é caracterizada como *Dado Aberto*. É uma leitura do dado efetuada por terceiros, e com um universo de uso muito restrito. A *utilidade pública* pressupõe que a *lista dos CEPs* possa ser utilizada pelos mais variados sistemas, de mapas a sistemas de logistica, públicos e privados, passando por aplicações do próprio governo como o SUS — ver padrão *DataSUS* e sistema em uso offline, assim como prejuízos já causados ao erário e saúde públicos pelo seu não-preenchimento nos formulários.

   1.6.2. não encontra-se disponível em mais de um endereço, e o único endereço não oferece garantia de persistência nem de confiabilidade. É sabido que tecnicamente a única forma de dar essa garantia é replicando-se o software em outros endereços (outros servidores) e outras redes (abertas e fechadas).

   1.6.3. a título de exemplo, o Brasil e os brasileiros investem, direta e indiretamente, milhões de reais todos os anos nos assim-chamados *sistemas CRM (Customer Relationship Management) e ERP (Enterprise Resource Planning)*: todos possuem módulos que requerem acesso de alta performance e confiabilidade, inclusive *offiline* (fora da Internet), à *Lista de CEPs*.
2. **O CEP é exigido pelo governo no nosso dia-a-dia, e uma exigência fixada em  Leis e em normas técnicas (que regulamentam Leis)**: são amplos e indiscutíveis os exemplos de caso onde o CEP é exigido, desde simples formulários (anexos a normas), a contratos, onde há exigência de preenchimento do CEP. Isso caracteriza a "contaminação" expressa no item 1.5 acima.
3. **Inconstitucionalidade**. A CONSTITUIÇÃO DA REPÚBLICA FEDERATIVA DO BRASIL DE 1988 (CF) em seu artigo 37 expressa a *obrigatoriedade da publicação*; em seu artigo 5º, inciso XIV, o *direito de acesso*; em seu artigo 216, § 2º, a *obrigatoriedade da franquia ao acesso*. Portanto, pelo item 2 acima, e pela CF, o ciadão não deve pagar pela *Lista de CEPs* (definida no item 1).

---

4. A seguir são ressubmetidos os argumentos não-respondidos, e acrescentadas breves respostas aos supostos argumentos de defesa da empresa.

   4.1. Bens públicos e informações públicas não são passíveis de exclusão por direitos autorais ou patente, deve-se ou anular a patente ou entender que o valor do produto está na forma muito particular e específica como a *Lista de CEPs* foi "embalada".

   4.1.1. Pode-se demonstrar "por absurdo" (*reductio ad absurdum*) que, se outras empresas registrassem direito sobre outras "formas de embalar a Lista de CEPs", estariam efetuando uma prática inconstitucional por tentar cercear o direito de acesso à informação. Podemos listar pelo menos 5 empresas "concorrentes do da ECT" que já vem buscando seu nicho de mercado em função das inconsistências jurídicas do "direito ao CEP".

   4.1.2. Parece-nos claro que o conteúdo de banco de dados não é objeto patenteável e, caso tal ocorra, poderá vir ser objeto de declaração de nulidade, por força do art. 46 da Lei 9.279/1996.

   4.2. Como já citado no item 1.6.3, muitos sistemas necessitam acesso à base de dados do CEP, porém hoje a empresa (ECT) impõe barreiras técnicas e financeiras ao acesso a estes dados. A falta de acesso livre à *Lista de CEPs* causa a disseminação de cópias desatualizadas, o que prejudica não apenas os usuários mas a própria ECT, uma vez que ela é obrigada a entregar correspondência mesmo com o CEP informado incorretamente. Portanto é do interesse do público e da própria ECT que a *Lista de CEPs* seja totalmente acessível.

   4.3. A Lei nº 6.538 de 1978, de onde se alega a sustentabilidade do monopólio da ECT, é anterior à Constituição de 1988, e não foi corrigida.

   4.3.1. À mesma época, em cumprimento ao disposto pelo caput do art. 15 da Lei Postal, a lista com o registro agregado dos Códigos de Endereçamento Postal era disponibilizada em toda agência da ECT, estando, portanto, ao alcance do cidadão o acesso à informação compilada (lista completa). A compra da lista era facultada no mesmo local, e não se pagavam por patentes ou direitos autorais, apenas pelo custo de impressão e distribuição.

   4.3.2. A Lei não veda a distribuição gratuita da lista, conforme §3º do art. 15, e que a busca e apreensão a que faz menção o §2º relaciona-se diretamente a eventuais receitas advindas de publicidade inserta em tais listas. Claro está que a renda de exploração da Lista não advém da informação nela contida, mas de seu uso para venda de produtos ou serviços agregados. Inexiste, portanto, disposição legal que dê ao CEP, individualizadamente considerado ou agregado em lista, caráter intrínseco de informação estratégica.

   4.3.3. Recordemos, nesse ponto, que é competência da União a manutenção do serviço postal, e não necessariamente a exploração, em monopólio, do mesmo. Em outras palavras, situa-se o desenvolvimento e atribuição de indexação a logradouros verdadeiro serviço público *uti universi*, que, apesar de servir ao bom desempenho da atividade econômica, com ela não se confunde. Se, portanto, a informação individualizada não pode ser considerada sigilosa ou privada, tampouco o poderá, pelos motivos expostos, a informação agregada numa *Lista de CEPs* completa, ou numa base de dados disposta como produto.

---

Caracterização mais completa da "Lista de CEPs" (depois podemos acrescentar modelo de dados UML) para caso coloquem em dúvida o seu significado:

- *Lista dos **logradouros** do município*: a cada item da lista o seu identificador e nome completo (unívoco) do logradouro. Toda "via de acesso" a um *endereço* é um logradouro.
- *Lista dos nomes de **bairros** município*: a cada item da lista o seu identificador e nome completo (unívoco) do bairro (denominação adotada para se referir a bairro ou loteamento).
- *Lista dos **CEPs comuns***: a cada item da lista a menor entidade de referência (região, logradouro, trecho de logradouro ou trecho e paridade de logradouro) associada ao respectivo código de CEP e respectivo identificador de logradouro.
- *Lista de **CEPs especiais***: ...

Comment: Olá, pessoal

Muito obrigado! Fico aguardando a contribuição de todos até amanhã

Comment: Olá, pessoal. O recurso foi enviado. Agora é só aguardar!

Answer (score -1):

Seguindo a sugestão do colega Jackson Emmerich, uma ideia é usar a API do site da [viacep.com.br](http://viacep.com.br).

A API deles pode ser usada dessas duas formas, dependendo do formato desejado para a saída:

```
http://viacep.com.br/ws/[cep-a-pesquisar]/[formato]
http://viacep.com.br/ws/[estado]/[cidade]/[string-de-busca]
```

Os formatos aceitos são o `json`, `xml`, `jsonp`, `querty` e `piped`.

## Busca por CEP

Eis aqui um exemplo, para o CEP 76.821-348, em JSON:

```
http://viacep.com.br/ws/76821348/json
```

```js
{
  "cep": "76821-348",
  "logradouro": "Rua Thales Benevides",
  "complemento": "",
  "bairro": "Rio Madeira",
  "localidade": "Porto Velho",
  "uf": "RO",
  "unidade": "",
  "ibge": "1100205",
  "gia": ""
}
```

O mesmo exemplo para XML:

```
http://viacep.com.br/ws/76821348/xml
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmlcep>
    <cep>76821-348</cep>
    <logradouro>Rua Thales Benevides</logradouro>
    <complemento/>
    <bairro>Rio Madeira</bairro>
    <localidade>Porto Velho</localidade>
    <uf>RO</uf>
    <unidade/>
    <ibge>1100205</ibge>
    <gia/>
</xmlcep>
```

Outro exemplo, para o CEP 01.001-000:

```
http://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json
http://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/xml
```

```js
{
  "cep": "01001-000",
  "logradouro": "Praça da Sé",
  "complemento": "lado ímpar",
  "bairro": "Sé",
  "localidade": "São Paulo",
  "uf": "SP",
  "unidade": "",
  "ibge": "3550308",
  "gia": "1004"
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmlcep>
    <cep>01001-000</cep>
    <logradouro>Praça da Sé</logradouro>
    <complemento>lado ímpar</complemento>
    <bairro>Sé</bairro>
    <localidade>São Paulo</localidade>
    <uf>SP</uf>
    <unidade></unidade>
    <ibge>3550308</ibge>
    <gia>1004</gia>
</xmlcep>
```

Para o formato JSONP, basta adicionar `?callback=nome_da_funcao` na URL terminada em JSON. Por exemplo:

```
http://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json?callback=foo
```

Dá como saída:

```js
foo({
  "cep": "01001-000",
  "logradouro": "Praça da Sé",
  "complemento": "lado ímpar",
  "bairro": "Sé",
  "localidade": "São Paulo",
  "uf": "SP",
  "unidade": "",
  "ibge": "3550308",
  "gia": "1004"
});
```

O formato piped (campos separados por `|` e chave separada de valor por `:`), é assim:

```
http://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/piped
```

```
cep:01001-000|logradouro:Praça da Sé|complemento:lado ímpar|bairro:Sé|localidade:São Paulo|uf:SP|unidade:|ibge:3550308|gia:1004
```

O formato querty é o formato usado em *query-strings* do tipo GET ou como corpo de requisição de formulários POST. Eis um exemplo:

```
http://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/querty
```

cep=01001-000&logradouro=Pra%C3%A7a+da+S%C3%A9&complemento=lado+%C3%ADmpar&bairro=S%C3%A9&localidade=S%C3%A3o+Paulo&uf=SP&unidade=&ibge=3550308&gia=1004

## Busca por endereço

Para a busca por endereços, o formato é quase o mesmo que a busca por CEPs (a diferença é que é trazida uma lista de logradouros ao invés de um único logradouro).

Eis aqui um exemplo:

```
http://viacep.com.br/ws/SP/S%C3%A3o%20Paulo/Vila%20Mariana/json
```

Eis a saída:

```
[
  {
    "cep": "04114-050",
    "logradouro": "Praça Lions Clube-Vila Mariana",
    "complemento": "",
    "bairro": "Jardim da Glória",
    "localidade": "São Paulo",
    "uf": "SP",
    "unidade": "",
    "ibge": "3550308",
    "gia": "1004"
  },
  {
    "cep": "04112-015",
    "logradouro": "Praça Comunitária da Vila Mariana",
    "complemento": "",
    "bairro": "Vila Mariana",
    "localidade": "São Paulo",
    "uf": "SP",
    "unidade": "",
    "ibge": "3550308",
    "gia": "1004"
  }
]
```