# Extrair dados de arquivo txt para usar em autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocompletar

> Update: Só pra constar, não tem necessidade de usar a jQuery-ui, pode ser com outra solução.

Estou criando um `autocomplete` para um formulário, onde devem constar todas as opções do [CBO - Código Brasileiro de Ocupações](http://www.mtecbo.gov.br/cbosite/pages/saibaMais.jsf)

Diferente do CEP, [que não possui uma base oficial gratuita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54539/cep-da-minha-cidade-onde-posso-encontrar-fonte-aberta-atualizada-e-confi%C3%A1vel), na [área de downloads do MTE](http://www.mtecbo.gov.br/cbosite/pages/downloads.jsf) existe um arquivo **txt**, onde são listadas as profissões e o código de cada uma (dentro da página do link acima tem o link: `Estrutura CBO (TXT) - Arquivo ZIP (106kb)` - é o quarto arquivo, **`CBO2002-Ocupacao.txt`**).

Então o que quero é pegar esse arquivo e gerar o código automaticamente, incluindo as profissões e os respectivos números do CBO no arquivo .js (como está no exemplo completo abaixo). Isso é possível?

Já criei o `autocomplete`, utilizando o plugin [JQuery-ui](https://code.jquery.com/ui/), mas desanimei de escrever todas as profissões e os códigos na unha e cá estou.

Além disso, preciso que o código não fique muito pesado e lento pra carregar. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso? Com banco de dados, tudo no arquivo .js?

Este é o `autocomplete` (coloquei todos os links externos e está funcionando em "executar trecho de código"):

```js
$(function() {

    var ocupacao = [

        "Abacaxicultor (CBO 6125-10)",
        "Abade (CBO 2631-05)",
        "Abadessa (CBO 2631-05)",
        "Abanador na agricultura (CBO 6220-20)",
        "Abastecedor de caldeira (CBO 8621-20)",
        "Abastecedor de linha de produção (CBO 7842-05)",
        "Abastecedor de máquinas de linha de produção (CBO 7842-05)",
        "Abastecedor de silos de carvão (CBO 6326-05)",
        "Abatedor (CBO 8485-05)"
    ];
    $("#profiss"). autocomplete({
        source:ocupacao
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" id="Cpost" name="Tpost">

<input type="text" id="profiss" placeholder="Informe a profissão"/>

</form>
```

Então, resumindo, as dúvidas são as seguintes:

1 - É possível criar o código automaticamente, à partir do arquivo .txt (ou html)? Como fazer isso?

2 - Como fazer para que o carregamento das opções não seja lento.

**Atualizando:** ainda não consegui, até fiz outro arquivo com as quebras de linhas (parece que o que dá pra baixar no site não tem quebras de linha) pra testar, mas ainda não consegui fazer o script funcionar. Conseguindo, posto o resultado aqui, mas se alguém tiver outra ideia estou aceitando também. :)

**Update:** Converti o pdf em arquivo html, e ele ficou com a seguinte estrutura (o arquivo inteiro tem mais 65k linhas):

```html
<DIV id="id_1">
<DIV id="id_1_1">
<TABLE cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class="t2">
<TR>
 <TD class="tr5 td4"><P class="p9 ft2"><NOBR>7681-25</NOBR></P></TD>
 <TD class="tr5 td5"><P class="p10 ft3">Acabador de chapéus de palha</P></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
 <TD class="tr6 td4"><P class="p9 ft2"><NOBR>7663-05</NOBR></P></TD>
 <TD class="tr6 td5"><P class="p10 ft4">Acabador de embalagens (flexíveis e cartotécnicas)</P></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</DIV>
```

Isso ajuda?

**/upate**

Comment: Gustavo, por que não utilizar um arquivo json que é muito mais "maleável"?

Comment: Vou ali procurar o que é Json e já volto. :D Mas acho que pode ser sim...

Comment: Tranquilo, pode ser sim (quem vê pensa que aprendi Json em dois minutos, kkk, mas só vi que vai dar pra entender depois de estudar um pouco)...

Comment: Um json é "basicamente" um objeto (ou array, ou array de objetos, ou objeto de arrays, etc...) em um arquivo externo, que você pode carregar com ajax no javascript, ou trabalhar com ele em qualquer outra linguagem, como PHP e etc...

Comment: Mas aí é só salvar o txt com a extensão .json?

Comment: Só pra constar, nós continuamos essa conversa no [chat de javascript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25038/javascript), e já evoluiu muito, mas ainda não foi solucionado...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O código a seguir gera o vetor de CBOs com exatamente a mesma estrutura do exemplo que você apresentou na pergunta, e então adiciona esse vetor como a fonte de dados do autocomplete.

```
$.get('ArquivoCbo.txt', function (conteudoDoArquivo) {
    var linhas = conteudoDoArquivo.split('\n');

    var profissoes = new Array();

    for (i = 2; i < linhas.length; i++) {
        var linha = linhas[i];
        var codigoDaProfissao = linha.split(" ")[0];
        var descricaoDaProfissao = linha.replace(codigoDaProfissao, "").trim();

        profissoes.push(descricaoDaProfissao + " (CBO " + codigoDaProfissao + ")");
    }

    $("#profiss"). autocomplete({
        source:profissoes
    });
});
```

Comment: Então, funcionou! Tava faltando fechar um parentese em `profissoes.push(descricaoDaProfissao + " (" + codigoDaProfissao + ")");` (o último) e segui a sugestão da minha IDE de simplificar `new Array() ` para apenas `[]`... funcionou legal, valeu mesmo!

Comment: É verdade, agora que reparei. O parênteses dentro da aspa no final da linha acabou me fazendo esquecer de fechar com o parêntese do push. Obrigado por me informar.

Aproveitando, @gustavox, sendo que minha solução funcionou, poderia marcá-la como a resposta para a pergunta, para ajudar as demais pessoas quando pesquisando esse mesmo problema. Obrigado. :)

Comment: Legal, só estava avisando no chat antes, porque tinham outros users tentando resolver também... Já marquei como aceita e concedi a recompensa, valeu mesmo! Abraços.

Answer (score 7):

No link que você mandou é possível baixar um TXT, com ele é bem mais simples de se trabalhar.

Segue o trecho do TXT em questão:

**CBO2002 - Ocupacao**

```
Codigo Titulo
------ ---------------------------------------------------------
010115 Oficial general da marinha
010110 Oficial general do exército
010105 Oficial general da aeronáutica
010210 Oficial do exército
010215 Oficial da marinha
010205 Oficial da aeronáutica
010315 Praça da marinha
010310 Praça do exército
010305 Praça da aeronáutica
020105 Coronel da polícia militar
020110 Tenente-coronel da polícia militar
020115 Major da polícia militar
```

você pode transformar este arquivo no source para o seu autocomplete da seguinte forma:

```
$.get('CBO2002 - Ocupacao.txt', function ()
    var linhas = arquivo.split('\n');
    var source = linhas.map(function(linha, indice) {
        if (indice >= 2) {
            var ocupacao = {
                Familia: linha.substring(0, 4),
                Codigo: linha.substring(4, 6),
                Titulo: linha.substring(7),
            };    
            return ocupacao.Titulo + " (CBO " + ocupacao.Familia + "-" + ocupacao.Codigo + ")";
        }
    });
    $("#profiss"). autocomplete({ source: source  });
});
```

Comment: Então, este arquivo que vc baixou é parte da estrutura do CBO (dos grupos). O que preciso é da listagem completa, que está no arquivo .pdf. Já consegui converter em txt, mas não ficou do mesmo jeito do que este que vc baixou. Cada profissão e código ficam em linhas separadas, e existem outras palavras (mas isso dá pra resolver fácil, só fazer uma busca e apagar o que não interessa). Vou começar a testar aqui o script que vc passou, e atualizo aqui com o progresso. Valeu mesmo! +rep

Comment: São 2 arquivos TXT, o arquivo 4 possui todas as ocupações, enquanto que o 3 os sinônimos.

Comment: É verdade, você tem razão! O que é embaraçoso, porque é algo que eu devia saber... Isso deve facilitar mesmo, porque o arquivo convertido do pdf tinha 65k linhas. Estou tentando aqui rodar o script, mas não tá dando certo. Coloquei entre as tags head, ou dentro do form, ou num arquivo externo, e parece que ele não tá achando o arquivo (que está na mesma pasta que o html)... também mudei o nome do arquivo pra evitar os espaços, mas acho que não era isso tbm... mas to testando aqui, assim que conseguir passo o resultado... Valeu!

Comment: Ao inspecionar pelo navegador recebo este erro para a segunda linha do script: Uncaught ReferenceError: arquivo is not defined. Já segui esta dica: http://fellipeguimaraes.com.br/tag/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined/ mas também não resolveu. E tem este erro também: GET http://localhost:63342/site/public_html/_javascript/jquery.min.map 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Estranho, tente acessar o arquivo TXT através de uma requisição AJAX.

Comment: Usando ajax (só mudar o get por ajax né?) o primeiro erro sumiu, ficou agora só este: 
 GET jquery.min.map:1http://localhost:63342/site/public_html/_javascript/jquery.min.map 404 (Not Found) Este arquivo jquery.min.map não existe mesmo, eu tenho que criá-lo? A única referencia a .map é na linha 3 do código. É pra ele criar este arquivo? pode ser erro de permissão? Pode ser alguma biblioteca faltando? Valeu pela paciência.

Comment: O método $.get apenas faz uma chamada ao método $.ajax com algumas opções pré configuradas, o mesmo vale para o $.post e outros.

Comment: Tente acessar o arquivo txt direto pelo navegador, tipo localhost:portNumber/fileName.txt, você consegue acessar? Caso contrário me.informe o erro.

Comment: Eu consigo abrir o txt normal. Seguindo um tópico do SOen (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found), instalei a jquery.min.map (que aparece como json no webstorm, é isso mesmo?), e linkei ela no html. Agora tá dando um erro diferente: Navigated to http://localhost:63342/site/public_html/_javascript/autocomplete.html
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token: jquery-2.1.3.min.map:1
XHR finished loading: GET .jquery-2.1.3.js:8625
"http://localhost:63342/site/public_html/_javascript/ocupacao.txt"

Comment: Achei este outro tópico, mas meu inglês é terrível: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143698/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token Agora acho que ele tá achando o arquivo txt, mas ainda não funcionou o autocomplete...

Comment: Apenas mais uma atualização, porque não sei quando voltarei a procurar esta solução: usando 'ajaxTransport', não recebo nenhum erro inspecionando pelo navegador, mas ainda não funcionou. Quando conseguir resolver, volto pra incluir o resultado.

Comment: Então, tentando manipular o arquivo, percebi que apesar da aparência, ele não está com um registro em cada linha. Pode ser isso que esteja fazendo o script não funcionar? Tem como resolver isso? Valeu.

Comment: Pode colocar algum exemplo que tenha mais de um registro por linha?

Comment: Então, criei outro arquivo txt com as linhas separadas mas não adiantou, continua o erro: XHR finished loading: GET jquery-2.1.3.js:8625 "http://localhost:63342/site/public_html/_javascript/ocupacao.txt". PS: A linha 8625 do jquery é `xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );`

Answer (score 5):

voce pode manipular o arquivo txt, fazendo um parse em cada linha, e salvá-las num array, ou concatenando numa única varável cada linha retornada.

algo como isso

```
$(function(){
       $.get('file.txt',function(data){
              var contents = $.trim(data).split(/\n/);
              console.log(contents.shift());
       });
});
```

Agora é só manipular cada contents[x] q será cada linha do arquivo e em seguida, se necessário separar profissao/valor, usar uma "," ou pipe"|" e dar outro split pra cada linha e armazenar em variáveis.
 seu codigo:

```
$(function() {
$.get('file.txt',function(data){
              var ocupacao= $.trim(data).split(/\n/);
 });

     $("#profiss"). autocomplete({
        source:ocupacao
    });

 });
```

isso considerando q o txt está com cada registro em uma linha.

Comment: Então, ainda sou iniciante, pareceu bem complicado pra mim... to estudando o parse aqui, mas não entendi uma coisa: teria que editar o arquivo txt inteiro, em cada linha? Consegui conveter o pdf em html, se puder dar uma olhada, editei o op incluindo um trecho do html. Vê se isso pode ajudar. Valeu.

Comment: no exemplo acima, eu fiz um split no \n, entao a variavel contents virou um array, ou seja, ele armazenou cada linha em uma posicao, contents[0] o q tem na linha 1, contents[1] o que tem na linha 2 etc... se substituir o console.log por  "alert(contents[0]);" ele mostrará num alerta toda a linha 1 do arquivo, e assim por diante, no caso se voce tiver um arquivo texto com as linhas como no exemplo acima, voce pode usar o contents como source:contents assim fica mais facil. ai ele entende q cada linha do seu txt é uma linha do seu array, apenas carregando o arquivo e dando um split no \n.

Comment: Valeu por ter editado a reposta, ficou mais claro. +rep

Comment: Então, tentando manipular o arquivo, percebi que apesar da aparência, ele não está com um registro em cada linha. Pode ser isso que esteja fazendo o script não funcionar? Tem como resolver isso? Valeu. –

Comment: só vendo mesmo... dependendo do SO pode ser necessário \n\r