# Como validar um cep no Android?

Tags: android, api, mobile, cep

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor maneira de fazer a validação de cep no Android. Tenho um formulário que o usuário digita o cep e quero retornar na tela se é válido ou não. E se possível retornar o endereço. Vi que o correio possui uma api em JSON que retorna o endereço a partir do cep, mas queria saber como implementar no meu sistema.

http://cep.correiocontrol.com.br/{CEP}.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, pra ficar claro esta **API** que você informou não é oficial dos *Correiros*. Este foi um assunto já bem discutido [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54539/cep-da-minha-cidade-onde-posso-encontrar-fonte-aberta-atualizada-e-confi%C3%A1vel) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/400/como-buscar-um-endere%C3%A7o-por-cep-nos-correios) sobre uma forma eficiente de obter estes dados.

Agora, se pretender mesmo utilizar a fonte deste site, basta fazer uma chamada simples com a classe [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) (em uma *thread* diferente, claro) e obter o resultado, que é um objeto **JSON**. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
private class BuscarCepTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        StringBuilder result = null;
        int respCode = -1;

        try {
            url = new URL("http://cep.correiocontrol.com.br/" + params[0] + ".json");
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            do {
                if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                    respCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                }
            } while (respCode == -1);

            if (respCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                httpURLConnection = null;
            }
        }

        return (result != null) ? result.toString() : null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

E fazer a chamada assim:

```
BuscarCepTask buscarCep = new BuscarCepTask();
buscarCep.execute("02011200");
```

O resultado que está no método `onPostExecute` vem no objeto que é um [`JSONObject`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), é só buscar `object.getString("logradouro")` e qualquer outra chave que tenha no objeto.

Comment: Depois que fui perceber que não é oficial dos correios. Mas quanto ao código, como irei pegar os valores do JSON e informar em uma TextView por exemplo?

Comment: Foi justamente minha observação final. Dentro de `object` você possui o que você precisa. Se quer o bairro, `object.getString("bairro")` e assim por diante, de acordo com a chave do *JSON*. E então é só definir o texto do seu `TextView` com estas informações.

Comment: Entendi, no caso como eu pegaria um cep específico de um EditText e colocaria como parâmetro ao invés de passar um cep qualquer?

Comment: Use `editText.getText().toString()`, onde `editText` é o seu objeto da interface. Assim você passa dentro do método onde eu estou usando *hard-code*.

Comment: Eu passo o objeto "logradouro" para meu TextView através do método setText ?

Comment: Se `logradouro` é uma *String*, sim.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23903/discussion-between-felipe-miranda-and-paulo-rodrigues).