# Como validar um CEP utilizando o jQuery.validate

Tags: jquery, validação, jquery-validate, cep

Não estou conseguindo validar um CEP digitado pelo usuário.

eu adicionei o seguinte código dentro do `jquery.validete.js`

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("cep", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}$/.test(value);
}, "Por favor, digite um CEP válido");
```

Porém se eu digitar: 11.111-111 ele aceita, quando na verdade este CEP não existe.

Comment: Bem vido ao SOpt Guilherme. Edite sua pergunte e agrupe seu código usando a opção de adicionar código, também sugiro um tour para aprender a perguntar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou utilizar o webservice gratuito http://viacep.com.br/

assim ele me retornará um JSON http://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/ 
que eu irei salvar em um objeto.

Obrigado @Sanção.

Comment: Guilherme, como você pegou o valor do JSON? e é possível preencher um campo automaticamente?

Answer (score 2):

Altere a expressão regular para:

```
/^[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{3}$/
```

O valor entre chaves define a quantidade de vezes que os caracteres entre colchetes vai se repetir, dessa forma a validação do valor 11.111-11 com `/^[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}$/` está correta

Comment: e teria como eu verificar se um CEP digitado realmente existe??

Comment: para isso você precisa consultar um serviço externo, existem perguntas aqui no site sobre o assunto: [CEP da minha cidade, onde posso encontrar fonte aberta, atualizada e confiável?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54539/13561) e [Como buscar um endereço por CEP nos Correios?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27267/13561)